# Como adicionar uma DIV a cada 3 parágrafos (<p>)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Bom o que eu quero é simples. Preciso adicionar uma div a cada 3 parágrafos. Lembrando que esses parágrafos estarão em uma outra div (no caso seria a div de conteúdo).

É parecido com a desse [site](http://hypescience.com/sonda-espacial-descobre-materia-de-fora-do-sistema-solar/), onde se encontra o anuncio.

Seria assim:

```
<div class="conteudo">
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <div class="anuncio">Div inserida</div>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <div class="anuncio">Div inserida</div>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Podes dar um exemplo do HTML a que te referes? Podes [edit] a pergunta e juntar o código aqui.

Comment: Bom, adicionei o código.

Answer (score 5):

Podes selecionar todos os `p` e depois usar o index deles dentro de um loop para contar/agrupar de três em três. Juntando a isso o `.insertAfter` tens o que precisas:

```
$('p').each(function(i) {
    var pos = i + 1;
    if (pos % 3 == 0) {
        $('<div/>', {
            class: 'anuncio',
            text: 'Div inserida!'
        }).insertAfter(this);
    }
});
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/k26973vz/

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente. Muito obrigado.
Tentei marca como resolvido mas parece que não posso ainda. Vlw

Comment: Como  eu poderia adicionar um script dentro dessa div?

Comment: @Helmesvs podes dar um exemplo de que script queres correr? Se queres inserir conteúdo de outro website pode ser caso de usar `iframe`.

Comment: É um anuncio:

`<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
descrColor="666666";titleColor="333333";urlColor="333333";borderColor="FFFFFF";bgColor="FFFFFF";altColor="FFFFFF";coddisplaysupplier="dd7bca939f064a9e89c7863c490e1de2";formatId="1";numads="4";deslabel="post";type="1";
-->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://adrequisitor-af.lp.uol.com.br/uolaf.js"></script>`

Comment: @Helmesvs é isto que procuras? https://jsfiddle.net/sn0zz83v/ Desaconselho a ter as variáveis globais dessa maneira. Daria uma pergunta interessante "como configurar/personalizar as variáveis do script".

Comment: Só esta imprimindo "anuncio". Mas o anuncio em si não aparece.

Comment: Alguém tem uma solução?

Comment: @Helmesvs isso é problema no teu script que estás a carregar via url. Acho que a tua pergunta original está resolvida, tens duas respostas. Se quiseres podes fazer uma nova pergunta para o problema que estás a ter agora.

Answer (score 3):

Pode utilizar uma fórmula `(an + b)` no seletor para especificar os elementos que deseja selecionar. Nesta fórmula `a` representa o tamanho ciclo, `n` é um contador (que começa em 0), e `b` é um valor de desvio.

**[Veja mais](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp)**

```js
$div = $('<div class="anuncio">DIV INSERIDA</div>');
$div.insertAfter('.conteudo p:nth-child(3n+0)');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="conteudo">
  <p>PARÁGRAFO</p>
  <p>PARÁGRAFO</p>
  <p>PARÁGRAFO</p>
  <p>PARÁGRAFO</p>
  <p>PARÁGRAFO</p>
  <p>PARÁGRAFO</p>
  <p>PARÁGRAFO</p>
  <p>PARÁGRAFO</p>
  <p>PARÁGRAFO</p>
  <p>PARÁGRAFO</p>
  <p>PARÁGRAFO</p>
  <p>PARÁGRAFO</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Boa ideia `nth-child(3n+0)` como seletor...  `+1`