# Como inserir anúncios a cada x parágrafos de texto

Tags: javascript, google-adsense

Estou utilizando o Wordpress (baseado em php, para quem não conhece) e gostaria de inserir um conteúdo a cada x parágrafos. Meu objetivo é colocar um código html ou javascript (um anúncio do Adsense ou publicidade direta, por exemplo) a cada 5 parágrafos (no meio do artigo que o usuário está lendo).

Eu encontrei [esse post](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/124324/como-adicionar-uma-div-a-cada-3-par%C3%A1grafos-p) que apresenta uma solução para esse problema em javascript, mas já faz anos que parei de programar por isso não consegui fazer funcionar no meu blog.

Observação: O código deve adicionar conteúdo apenas no texto que estiver dentro da div entry-content. Esta é a div onde a postagem que o usuário lê se localiza.

Edit: O uso de plugins prontos está fora de cogitação.

Edit 2: Esse é o código que encontrei e que resolve parcialmente meu problema. Não serve pra mim porque com ele eu posso usar apenas texto, não posso usar um código html, chamar uma página em php ou inserir um javascript

```
$('p').each(function(i) {
var pos = i + 1;
if (pos % 3 == 0) {
    $('<div/>', {
        class: 'anuncio',
        text: 'Div inserida!'
    }).insertAfter(this);
   }
});
```

Edit 3: Esse é o codigo javascript (anúncio do adsense) que eu preciso inserir na página. É contra as regras do Google Adsense alterar mesmo q minimamente esse código

```
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:block; text-align:center;"
     data-ad-format="fluid"
     data-ad-layout="in-article"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-6765322619356148"
     data-ad-slot="6356279518"></ins>
<script>
     (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```

Comment: Olá Pablo. 
Tenta procurar por um plugin que faça o inserimento de propagandas, é um modo mais fácil de lidar com esse problema.

Comment: poste aqui o seu código para a gente ver o que possa estar mal

Comment: Mateus, não gosto de usar plugins porque deixa o site pesado e minha hospedagem não é das melhores.

Comment: Tmc, eu não cheguei a criar um código. Tem este aqui que eu vi em outro tópico (link no post inicial), mas é em javascript e aceita apenas texto, no meu caso preciso de algo que aceite html e javascript:
`
$('p').each(function(i) {
    var pos = i + 1;
    if (pos % 3 == 0) {
        $('<div/>', {
            class: 'anuncio',
            text: 'Div inserida!'
        }).insertAfter(this);
    }
});
`

Comment: @Pablo a outra resposta à questão que você lincou traz a solução para o seu problema. Ao invés de criar uma `div` passando um objeto como segundo parâmetro você pode passar direto o html completo da div, que pode conter qualquer conteúdo.

Comment: @RicardoMoraleida eu sei que a base do problema foi resolvida no outro tópico mas realmente não consegui fazer funcionar (inclusive no outro topico a pessoa teve o msm problema, so conseguia inserir texto). Vc poderia me enviar o código completo?
Eu tentei mudar o conteúdo lá de "text" para "html" e colocar o código javascript do anúncio Adsense, mas não deu certo. Eu consegui apenas usar html puro como negrito, cor da fonte, etc, mas um código javascript ou php não.

Eu até baixei umas apostilas de javascript e de php pra voltar a programar mas isso leva tempo e eu tenho urgência.

Comment: Este link estava no comentário da primeira resposta e tem um exemplo funcional de como puxar scripts usando o mesmo código da sua pergunta: https://jsfiddle.net/sn0zz83v/

Comment: @RicardoMoraleida cara ja to envergonhando aqui, eu vi esse código também, briguei com ele mas não consegui fazer funcionar. Editei o post principal com o código do script que eu preciso inserir, se puder dar uma olhada eu agradeço.

Desculpa ae pela ignorância, sei q não faz muito sentido estar em um fórum de programadores sem saber programar minimamente mas é q to realmente sem alternativas.

Comment: @Pablo não tem que ficar envergonhado, todo mundo começa de algum lugar. O problema desse post é que a pergunta que você tinha feito já estava respondida. Esse é o exercício principal a se fazer. Se a resposta à pergunta que você fez não te atende, é sinal que a pergunta a ser feita deve ser outra. Depois da edição ficou mais claro o problema e é possível te ajudar.

Answer (score 0):

**Após a edição da pergunta:**

Me parece que o problema é que você está inserindo o script `adsbygoogle.js` a cada anuncio quando na verdade você deve inserir uma vez só, assim como o `(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});` deve ser usado uma vez só, que é a parte que inicializa os anúncios.

No exemplo abaixo você vê somente a tag `<ins></ins>` sendo inserida entre os parágrafos (abra o console para ver).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Num sistema configurado para receber os anúncios essa implementação deve funcionar.

```js
$div = $('<ins class="adsbygoogle"   style="display:block; text-align:center;"     data-ad-format="fluid" data-ad-layout="in-article" data-ad-client="ca-pub-6765322619356148" data-ad-slot="6356279518"</ins>');

$div.insertAfter('p:nth-child(3n+0)');

(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>paragrafo</p>
<p>paragrafo</p>
<p>paragrafo</p>
<p>paragrafo</p>
<p>paragrafo</p>
<p>paragrafo</p>
<p>paragrafo</p>
<p>paragrafo</p>
<p>paragrafo</p>
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
```