# CASAR terceiro elemento REGEX

Tags: regex

Como faço para casar somente o terceiro `</p>` desse texto?

```
texto="<p>primeiro paragrafo.</p><h2>titulo 1</h2><p>segundo  paragrafo.</p><h2>titulo 2</h2><p>terceiro paragrafo.</p> <p>primeiro paragrafo.</p><h2>titulo 1</h2><p>segundo  paragrafo.</p><h2>titulo 2</h2><p>terceiro paragrafo.</p> <p>primeiro paragrafo.</p><h2>titulo 1</h2><p>segundo  paragrafo.</p><h2>titulo 2</h2>"
```

Regex:
https://regex101.com/r/O1NTvP/1

Comment: Favor ler [essa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/129557/75104)

Comment: Então não é possivel casar somente o terceiro </p>.

Comment: A maneira mais simples seria utilizar a programação, ou seja, usar a expressão para buscar todos os `</p>` e pegar o terceiro utilizando a lógica de programação.

Comment: Qual linguagem de programação pretende usar? ASP Clássico (vb) ou em JavaScript (front-end)?

Comment: Asp classic. Vb

Comment: Cara na verdade o que estou tentando fazer é o seguinte. pegar esse </p> que é o fim do paragráfo, em um texto corrente e substituir por outra coisa, logo após esse </p>, seria um banner em javscript. (Tentei em javscrit, porém seria um javscript dentro de outro, sem sucesso). Só que teria que ser nesse terceiro </p>, ou quarto, a minha escolha. Pensei em regex.

Comment: Ou seja, quero incluir um javascript (adsense), logo após o fechamento do terceiro </p>

Comment: Pensei que em regex conseguiria casar o mesmo caracter, na posição que eu escolhesse no texto.

Comment: Pelo que entendi vc quer pegar o segundo `<p></p>` e colocar depois dele um elemento que vai ficar antes do terceiro `<p></p>`  correto? Pode ser com jQuery?

Comment: não dá, porque o que quero colocar é também javscrit, um banner do adsense. já até olhei esse código aqui que não funcionaria com um script dentro de outro. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/227387/como-inserir-an%c3%bancios-a-cada-x-par%c3%a1grafos-de-texto

Comment: Isso que quero, porém aqui é plugin do wordpress. https://www.estudopratico.com.br/sincretismo-religioso/ nota que os anuncios são exibidos no correr do texto.

Comment: Pelo que entendi, seria melhor trabalhar com manipulação de DOM. Plota na tela (ou em um DOM artificial) e adiciona a subárvore desejada logo antes do terceiro parágrafo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dá pra fazer quebrando a string `texto` em array pelas tags `</p>` e depois remontando o `texto` com `For Each` adicionando novamente as tags `</p>` e quando chegar na terceira volta do laço, acrescentar o que você quer após a terceira tag `</p>`. É só usar uma variável que comece do `0` e a cada volta do `For Each` incrementar `+1`. Quando o valor dessa variável for `2` (significa que o laço está na 3ª volta), adicione numa variável que possui a tag `</p>` o conteúdo que você quer inserir após ela, no caso o código do Adsense.

Ficaria assim:

```
<%
texto="<p>primeiro paragrafo.</p><h2>titulo 1</h2><p>segundo paragrafo.</p><h2>titulo 2</h2><p>terceiro paragrafo.</p> <p>primeiro paragrafo.</p><h2>titulo 1</h2><p>segundo  paragrafo.</p><h2>titulo 2</h2><p>terceiro paragrafo.</p> <p>primeiro paragrafo.</p><h2>titulo 1</h2><p>segundo  paragrafo.</p><h2>titulo 2</h2>"
texto2 = split(texto, "</p>") ' quebra em array
texto = "" ' esvazia a variável

indice = 0 ' cria a variável
For Each item In texto2
   if indice = 2 then
      fecha_p = "</p><script async src=""//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js""></script>"&_
      "<ins class=""adsbygoogle"""&_
      " style=""display:inline-block;width:300px;height:250px"""&_
      " data-ad-client=""ca-pub-3438726300391994"""&_
      " data-ad-slot=""5174009669""></ins>"&_
      "<script>"&_
      "(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});"&_
      "</script>"
   else
      fecha_p = "</p>"
   end if

   texto = texto & item & fecha_p ' concatena as strings
   indice = indice + 1 ' incrementa a variável
Next
%>
```

O resultado da variável `texto` ficará assim:

```
<p>primeiro paragrafo.</p><h2>titulo 1</h2><p>segundo paragrafo.</p><h2>titulo 2</h2><p>terceiro paragrafo.</p><script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script><ins class="adsbygoogle" style="display:inline-block;width:300px;height:250px" data-ad-client="ca-pub-3438726300391994" data-ad-slot="5174009669"></ins><script>(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});</script> <p>primeiro paragrafo.</p><h2>titulo 1</h2><p>segundo  paragrafo.</p><h2>titulo 2</h2><p>terceiro paragrafo.</p> <p>primeiro paragrafo.</p><h2>titulo 1</h2><p>segundo  paragrafo.</p><h2>titulo 2</h2></p>
```

Repare que o código do Adsense ficou posicionado após o terceiro `</p>`. Se quiser após o 4º, por exemplo, basta trocar o `2` em `if indice = 2 then` por `3`.

Note também que é preciso duplicar as aspas duplas dos atributos do script do Adsense para escapar as aspas duplas que delimitam a string da variável `fecha_p`.

No código acima eu coloquei um Adsense meu, não esqueça de trocar pelos valores do seu Adsense.

**Com JavaScript:**

Busque o terceiro parágrafo dentro de uma div (é preciso que os parágrafos estejam dentro de uma div pai) e adicione o código do Adsense após ele:

```
<%
texto="<p>primeiro paragrafo.</p><h2>titulo 1</h2><p>segundo paragrafo.</p><h2>titulo 2</h2><p>terceiro paragrafo.</p> <p>primeiro paragrafo.</p><h2>titulo 1</h2><p>segundo  paragrafo.</p><h2>titulo 2</h2><p>terceiro paragrafo.</p> <p>primeiro paragrafo.</p><h2>titulo 1</h2><p>segundo  paragrafo.</p><h2>titulo 2</h2>"
%>
<div id="texto">
   <%=texto%>
</div>
<script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){

   var p = document.querySelectorAll("#texto > p")[2];

   var adsense = document.createRange().createContextualFragment('<scr'+'ipt async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"><\/script>'
                  +'<ins class="adsbygoogle"'
                       +' style="display:inline-block;width:300px;height:250px"'
                       +' data-ad-client="ca-pub-3438726300391994"'
                       +' data-ad-slot="5174009669"></ins>'
                  +'<scr'+'ipt>'
                  +'(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});'
                  +'<\/script>');

   document.getElementById("texto").insertBefore(adsense, p.nextSibling);

});
</script>
```

Veja que é preciso escapar a barra invertida do fechamento da tag `</script>` do Adsense e concatenar a palavra `script`: `<scr'+'ipt`. Senão o JavaScript entenderá que você está colocando um script dentro de outro.

Só que os métodos `document.createRange().createContextualFragment()` podem não funcionar em navegadores mais antigos.

**Com jQuery:**

É um pouco mais simples. O seletor `$("#texto p:eq(2)")` seleciona o terceiro parágrafo dentro de `#texto` e o `.after()` insere o HTML após ele:

```
$(function(){
   var adsense = '<scr'+'ipt async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"><\/script>'
                  +'<ins class="adsbygoogle"'
                       +' style="display:inline-block;width:300px;height:250px"'
                       +' data-ad-client="ca-pub-3438726300391994"'
                       +' data-ad-slot="5174009669"></ins>'
                  +'<scr'+'ipt>'
                  +'(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});'
                  +'<\/script>';

  $("#texto p:eq(2)").after(adsense);
});
```

Comment: vou ver aqui, valeu, teria que dar um lopping no texto inteiro nê.

Comment: rapaz...não tem na web brasil um código que faça isso, já olhei tudo.

Comment: Seria um looping na array gerada a partir do texto.

Comment: Mas é possível fazer isso com JS tb. Basta injetar o código do Adsense após o terceiro parágrafo.

Comment: como injeta um javscript dentro de outro?

Comment: vou colocar seu codigo em uma função, deu certinho, depois vou ver também a possiblidade de se eu quiser colocar em mais paragrafos.

Comment: Coloquei na resposta algumas alternativas com JS.

Comment: Perfeito, já está até rodando. Vou ver agora se consigo contar os </p> e só exibir de tiver nais de x </p>, ou exibir indice =2 or indice=5...caso o texto for grande.